# Ovveride UserCreationForm errors message in django

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication, django-models

Hi i extend **UserCreationForm** form and my new form is like:

```
class create_user_form(UserCreationForm):
email=forms.EmailField(label='ایمیل',widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'user@mail.com',}))
# username=forms.CharField(error_messages={'username': 'Please let us know what to call you!'},label='نام کاربری',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'مثال : Mohammad',}))
first_name=forms.CharField(label='نام',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'نام واقعی',}))
last_name=forms.CharField(label='فامیلی',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'فامیلی واقعی',}))
class Meta:
    model=User
    fields=['username','email','first_name','last_name']


def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super(UserCreationForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class']='form-control'
    self.fields['username'].label='نام کاربری'
    self.fields['username'].help_text=''
    self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class']='form-control'
    self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class']='form-control'
    self.fields['password1'].label='رمز عبور'
    self.fields['password2'].label='تایید پسورد'
    self.fields['password1'].help_text=''
    self.fields['password2'].help_text=''
```

So i ovveride labels and help_text of form inputs to my own language
But i can't find a way to ovveride error message that occur when submitting form

Also i have tried

```
    username=forms.CharField(error_messages={'username': 'Please let us know what to call you!'},label='نام کاربری',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'مثال : Mohammad',}))
```

But it dosen't work

Can you help me to change error messages of form?

Comment: The error_messages attribute needs to be a dictionary of error keys to their actual messages, for instance `required` or `max_length`, as detailed in [the form fields documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#charfield).

Comment: @DanielRoseman But i want to make sure that user dosen't input for example !,% , ... in charfield and also i  want to show my own error in my language

Comment: Well, for localising to your own language, you should read the [internationalization and localization docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/#internationalization-and-localization) rather than setting everything manually. But adding specific validation isn't a job for the error_messages attribute, it's a job for [validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute).

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for your help